# How to display an additional span before the option names with Chosen or another dropdown plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I need to add a dropdown where options can be filtered on the fly when on starts to type some word (exactly what [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) does) AND where a `span` is always displayed before each option, similar to the Google Drive search bar:

[image: img]

(in this example icons are displayed, but I just need to display a `span` tag)

"always displayed" in the sense that the span tag should be displayed at the initial display of the dropdown, but also when the list of options starts being filtered, or when an option is selected.

With Chosen I've tried to do this this way:

```js
$select.on("chosen:showing_dropdown", function() {
  $(".chosen-results").find('li').each(function(index) {
    if(index !== 0) { // ignore the "prompt" li
      var courseName = $(this).html();
      $(this).html("<span style='color: red'>foo</span> " + courseName);
    }
  });
});
```

It works when the dropdown is first displayed by Chosen, but as soon as I start typing something the filtered list of results loses my `span` tags. I can't find [a chosen event](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html#triggered-events) that is triggered when the list starts being filtered.

Is there a way to achieve what I need with Chosen, or with any other similar plugin?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly then in the `<li>` element you want to put your span ? Try below:

```
$select.on("chosen:showing_dropdown", function() {
  $(".chosen-results").find('li').each(function(index) {
    if(index !== 0) { // ignore the "prompt" li
      var courseName = $(this).html();   
       $(this).prepend("<span style='color: red'>foo</span> " + courseName);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: it was already working, my question is how to make sure the prepend tag is still displayed after one starts filtering the dropdown

Comment: Hi I am not very much familiar with chosen plugin can you share your code in plunker or JSfiddle ?